# What are the differences bewteen maxJsonLength and MaxJsonDeserializerMembers?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

We can set the max json length in the web.config in two ways:

1: in bytes

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000">
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

2: in the app settings. The max entries in the json object (this case 150,000)

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
```

I am wondering, when to use which one? Do I always need both? Are those two working with each other some way?

Answer (score 5):

By definition here are the two settings in question.

1. [**JavaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

   > Gets or sets the maximum length of JSON strings that are accepted by the JavaScriptSerializer class.
2. [**aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

   > Specifies the limit of the maximum number of **items** that can be present in any dictionary deserialized by the JavaScriptSerializer type.

That said, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207539/5233410) answer

> The value of the MaxJsonLength property applies only to the internal
>   JavaScriptSerializer instance that is used by the asynchronous
>   communication layer to invoke Web services methods. [(MSDN:
>   ScriptingJsonSerializationSection.MaxJsonLength
>   Property)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.scriptingjsonserializationsection.maxjsonlength.aspx)

And the answerer's interpretation

> Basically, the "internal" JavaScriptSerializer respects the value of
>   maxJsonLength when called from a web method; direct use of a
>   JavaScriptSerializer (or use via an MVC action-method/Controller) does
>   not respect the maxJsonLength property, at least not from the
>   systemWebExtensions.scripting.webServices.jsonSerialization section of
>   web.config.